# Difference between expected_nodes and recover_after_nodes parameters

Tags: elasticsearch

I can't see the difference between two parameters for the recovery phase of the gateway module.

In the [documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-gateway.html#recover-after) :

- The `gateway.recover_after_nodes` setting (which accepts a number) controls **after how many (...) eligible nodes (...) recovery will start**.
- The `gateway.expected_nodes` allows to set **how many (...) eligible nodes** are expected to be in the cluster, and **once met, (...) recovery starts**

From what I understand, these two settings trigger the recovery phase once the number of node is equal to the value set.

Why using one over the other?

And what is the point of using both of them?

For example :

```
gateway:
    recover_after_nodes: 3
    expected_nodes: 5
```

In this case, what is the purpose of `expected_nodes`? recovery will be triggered as soon as there will be 3 nodes. There must be another reason to use it.

I hope my question is clear enough.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When using recovery_after_nodes, recover_after_data_nodes or recovery_after_master_nodes, once all set conditions are met the cluster will then start waiting recover_after_time before starting recovery:

> The gateway.recover_after_time setting (which accepts a time value)
>   sets the time to wait till recovery happens once all
>   gateway.recover_after...nodes conditions are met.

When using expected_nodes, expected_data_nodes or expected_master nodes, recovery will start once all conditions are met - the cluster will not wait. In addition, it will also default recovery_after_time to 5 min.

In your test case:

```
gateway:
    recover_after_nodes: 3
    expected_nodes: 5
```

Once you hit 3 nodes a countdown clock starts and the cluster will then recovery in either 5 minutes (the default) or if you hit 5 nodes. Basically it allows you to set a minimum threshold (recovery_after_nodes), with a timeout (recovery_after_time) to wait for a desired state (expected_nodes). You will either recovery recovery_after_time after recovery_after_nodes is hit, or when expected_nodes is hit (no additional waiting) - whichever comes first.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification : it now makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

from the public document, there are misunderstandings in this threads.

http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/modules-gateway.html

```
gateway:
recover_after_time: 5m
expected_nodes: 2
```

> In an expected 2 nodes cluster will cause recovery to start 5 minutes
>   after the first node is up, but once there are 2 nodes in the cluster,
>   recovery will begin immediately (without waiting).

so, the timer defined by recover_after_time will start already after a first node is up. not start after finding nodes defined in recover_after_nodes